# TextField Validation

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ipad

I have a TextField in my iPad application. I want the "Number Pad" to come on touch (without the punctuation marks and Alphabet Keyboard Button).How do I do that ? How to validate the TextField ?

Comment: try to design custom keyboard yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the textField keyboard = NumberPad in your interface builder.

Thanks

Mitesh

Comment: First of all I'm not using Interface Builder.
Second thing - If I'll set it as UIKeyBoardNumberPad is also gives the special characters which I don't want.

Comment: For number and Punctuation keyboard type is UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation and for only numbers keyboard type is  UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad. please check.

Comment: Then use regular expressions to validate you number.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *nameRegex =@"[0-9]"; 
NSPredicate *nameTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegex]; 
BOOL isNumber=[nameTest evaluateWithObject:string];

if(isNumber) {
  // valid number found
} else {
  // error message
}
```

Use this validation code in the UITextField delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` to prevent the user from even entering an invalid value.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get a number pad on ipad.You yourself have to put a check what the user has entered from keyboard, if its not number show them an alert to enter numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use with askee mumber validation as below I have made validation in which I have consider onley numeric and back button.

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

  if([string isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 48]]||[string isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 49]] ||[string isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 50]] ||[string isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 51]] ||[string isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 52]] ||[string isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 53]] ||[string isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 54]] ||[string isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 55]] ||[string isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 56]] ||[string isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 57]] || [string isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 46]]||[string isEqualToString:@""])

    {

    if(textField==myText)
        return  YES;
    else 
        return NO;
}
else 
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a number pad implementation for the iPad: https://github.com/IngmarStein/NumericKeypad

Disclaimer: it's my own fork of azu's NumericKeypad

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: Also, you don't actually address the OP's question: they want a number pad without certain characters, or code that validates against them.

Comment: The OP wants a keyboard without alphabetic characters. The library above includes the decimal separator but can easily be extended to hide it.

Comment: They want it without the alphabet *keyboard button* at all, even. And don't forget my first comment, above. It's actually the most important here, as this post risks being flagged as spam as it is now.

Comment: Yes, it does not include the "alphabet keyboard button" at all. I've added the disclaimer. Let the OP decide if the answer applies to his case or not.

Comment: Hi Ingmar...Welcome to our site. There's probably a couple things you might not be aware of here that makes us different from all the other sites out there. 1. We don't consider "link only" answers particularly useful and prefer to see a more substantial solution described here with links to external content provided purely for reference. 2. I would be wary of frequently posting links to your own content unless it is to provide reference material to an already chunky answer. Thanks.